# In Python 2.5, how do I kill a subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using the subprocess package in Python to run a subprocess, which I later need to kill. However, the documentation of the subprocess package states that the terminate() function is only available from 2.6

We are running Linux with 2.5 and for backwards compatibility reasons I cannot upgrade to 2.6, what is the alternative? I am guessing that these functions are convenience methods for something.

Comment: Cool: If I glue the answers together I get 'portable' code !

Comment: There is an already glued portable answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8536476/192632

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You call os.kill on the process pid.

```
os.kill(process.pid, signal.SIGKILL)
```

You're OK because you're on on Linux.  Windows users are out of luck.

Comment: os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGTERM) to be more precise

Comment: "kill 123" sends SIGTERM. "kill -9 123" sends SIGKILL. Be nice to the process and try SIGTERM first.

Answer (score 40):

To complete @Gareth's answer, on Windows you do:

```
import ctypes
PROCESS_TERMINATE = 1
handle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, False, theprocess.pid)
ctypes.windll.kernel32.TerminateProcess(handle, -1)
ctypes.windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(handle)
```

not quite as elegant as `os.kill(theprocess.pid, 9)`, but it does work;-)

Answer (score 6):

In order to complete @Gareth's and @Alex answers, if you don't want to bother with the underlaying system, you can use [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil).

> psutil is a module providing an
>   interface for retrieving information
>   on running processes and system
>   utilization (CPU, memory) in a
>   portable way by using Python,
>   implementing many functionalities
>   offered by command line tools like ps,
>   top, kill and Windows task manager.
>
> It currently supports Linux, OS X,
>   FreeBSD and Windows with Python
>   versions from 2.4 to 3.1 by using a
>   unique code base.

Answer (score 4):

Thats a copy&pase complete solution:

```
def terminate_process(pid):
    # all this shit is because we are stuck with Python 2.5 and 
    # we cannot use Popen.terminate()
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        import ctypes
        PROCESS_TERMINATE = 1
        handle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, False, pid)
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.TerminateProcess(handle, -1)
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(handle)
    else:
        os.kill(pid, signal.SIGKILL)
```

Accepting bug reports as comments ;)